# pandas take last consecutive value

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas DataFrame with column:

```
index, min_or_max
0,     np.nan
1,     np.nan
2,     min
3,     np.nan
4,     np.nan
5,     max
6,     np.nan
7,     np.nan
8,     np.nan
9,     max
10,    np.nan
11,    np.nan
12,    min
```

I want to create `col2` such that:

```
index, min_or_max, col2
0,     np.nan      np.nan
1,     np.nan      np.nan
2,     min         min
3,     np.nan      np.nan
4,     np.nan      np.nan
5,     max         np.nan
6,     np.nan      np.nan
7,     np.nan      np.nan
8,     np.nan      np.nan
9,     max         max
10,    np.nan      np.nan
11,    np.nan      np.nan
12,    min         min
```

how can I check for consecutive values in the column and take the last one?

- I can have multiple consecutive value max or min but repetition is max 10 in a row
- I can have repetitions of either in or max value

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
df1 = df[df['min_or_max'].ne(df['min_or_max'].shift(-1))]
df1["col2"] = df1["min_or_max"]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1 = df1[["index", "col2"]]


df = df.reset_index()
df = df[["index"]]

df = df.merge(df1, on="index", how="left")
```

EDIT:

my proposed solution:

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=['min_or_max'], how='all', inplace=False)
df1 = df1[df1['min_or_max'].ne(df1['min_or_max'].shift(-1))]


df = df.reset_index()
df = df[["index", "min_or_max"]]

df1 = df1.reset_index()
df.columns = ["index", "col2"]

df1 = df1[["index", "col2"]]
df = df.merge(df1, on="index", how="left")
```

Comment: What data type is your 'min_or_max' column? Are `min`, `max` functions that are stored in the dataframe?? Or are they strings, or numbers that you just replaced with words?

Comment: doubles replaced with strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example:**

```py
s = pd.Series(['A', np.nan, 'A', 'bb', 'bb', 'A', 'A', 'bb', 'A', 'bb', 'bb'])

0       A
1     NaN
2       A
3      bb
4      bb
5       A
6       A
7      bb
8       A
9      bb
10     bb
dtype: object
```

**Solution:**

In each group: leave only the **last** value. (`NaN`s are considered parts of the groups.)

```py
s = s.bfill()
to_delete = s == s.shift(-1)
s[to_delete] = np.nan
```

**Result:**

```py
0     NaN
1     NaN
2       A
3     NaN
4      bb
5     NaN
6       A
7      bb
8       A
9     NaN
10     bb
dtype: object
```

Comment: what if I have [min, max, min, max, max, min, min, max, min, max, max] then in such case I want to preserve values and get [min, max, min, skip, max, skip, min, max, min, skip, max] where skip means i want to skip these indexes

Comment: I want to get last value from consequetive group. consequetive group means either min group or max group interrupted by opposite so min, min, max gives me skip, min, max

Comment: similarly: min, min, min, max, min, min, min,min, max, max gives me: skip, skip, min, max, skip, skip, skip, min, skip, max

Comment: my bad. well spotted. I am sure it mislead you. i do apologize for the mistake in the original example!

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki, added solution